# SQL Server : set value where row id is same

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms, sql-server-2017

I am using SQL Server and I'm facing an issue. I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`.

`Table1` has a column `VALUE` and `table2` has two columns `Id` and `Wiegand_Id`.

What I want to do is set the columns's `VALUE` (in `table1`) to the values of `Wiegand_Id`, where their id's are the same.

I'll give you below some screenshots of these tables, so you can understand what I want to do.

[Here's table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjvqt.png)

[Here's table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUEmC.png)

[And here's all the tables, including the last one which is the updated table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTVsW.png)

I've tried this query below,

```
UPDATE [table2]
SET value = (SELECT [table1].[wiegand id]
             FROM [table1]
             WHERE [table2].[value] = [table1].[id])
```

but it shows me an error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'VALUE', table 'table2'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Although there are no null values in both tables.

If anyone can show me what I'm doing wrong and what changes should I make into this query in order to make it work, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you take the time to do a mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, this will be easier to solve. That means providing table creation and population scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` or `APPLY` :

```
update t2
     set t2.value = t1.[wiegand id]
from table2 t2 inner join
     table1 t1
     on t1.id = t2.value;
```

`APPLY` Version should be :

```
update t2
     set t2.value = t1.[wiegand id]
from table2 t2 cross apply
     (select top (1) t1.[wiegand id]
      from table1 t1
      where t1.id = t2.value
     ) t1;
```

For this query :

```
UPDATE [table2]
SET value = (SELECT [table1].[wiegand id]
             FROM [table1]
             WHERE [table2].[value] = [table1].[id]
            )
```

Will perform `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so, the error would be obvious. But, your Data suggests NO Error. So, i would suggest to update the table via `INNER JOIN`s to avoid error.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE [table2]
SET [table2].value = [table1].[wiegand id]
FROM [table1]
INNER JOIN [table2] ON [table1].[wiegand id] = [table2].value
```